# setValue() sets entire row not one cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm just not getting this.  I simply want to copy the value from one cell to another in the same row.  Simple right?  Well, it fills every cell (to the right) with the value instead of just one cell.  I've racked my brain over this and I guess I'm just not understanding something.

```
/* This gets the entire sheet (range) doesn't it? */
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
var rowRange ;
var status ;
var notes ;

var i=981;
var theEnd=979; 


  for (; i > theEnd; i--) {
     rowRange = range.offset(i, 0, 1); // Doesn't this specify one row (range) ?
     status = rowRange.offset(0, statusColumnOffset).getValue();  // one cell, right? 
     notes = rowRange.offset(0, notesColumnOffset).getValue();

    /* it gets the correct value for notes */
    if (notes == "No Number") {
// copy notes cell to status cell
/* I've tried both this (first attempt): */      
      //rowRange.offset(0, statusColumnOffset).setValue("No Number");

/* and this (second attempt):  */
      statusCell = rowRange.offset(0, statusColumnOffset);
      statusCell.setValue("No Number");
/* both give the same results */

    }
```

Now I'm puzzled why my first attempt with "rowRange.offset(0, statusColumnOffset).setValue("No Number");" did what it did.  It gets the value of one cell just fine.  So why in the world does the identical code (other than setting instead of getting) result in a full row being set with the value in each cell??  I'm just as puzzled as to why my second attempt gives the same (wrong) results.  What is it I'm not understanding?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rowRange = range.offset(i, 0, 1); // Doesn't this specify one row (range) ?
```

Yes it does, a range that is as wide as the number of populated columns in the sheet. So this:

```
statusCell = rowRange.offset(0, statusColumnOffset);
```

will be just as wide. I believe you would need to use:

```
statusCell = rowRange.offset(0, statusColumnOffset, 1, 1);
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#offset

> If the optional numRows and numColumns are not specified, the offset
>   range returned will have the same size as the initial range, otherwise
>   the returned Range is resized.

Comment: I read the docs several times before posting.  I understood some of it, but obviously not all.  Your explanation shed a truckload of light on the subject though.  Now I understand why the setValue() does what it does, but suddenly the getValue() leaves me scratching my head as to why in fact it does work.  Based on what you've said, I would think that the getValue() which also uses offset() would get a row of values instead of just one cell.  Maybe that is in fact what it's doing and I simply  haven't noticed it because all the cells to the right are currently blank?  <continued>

Comment: Or maybe I'm just not access it properly to see all of the values it (will eventually be) loaded up with and I have a built-in bug waiting to bite me?

Comment: As I understand it, if you apply getValue() to a range bigger than one cell, it will only get the top-left value. If your use case requires you to get all the values in a range, you should use getValues().

Comment: No it's doing what I need done, it just confused me as to why virtually the exact same code works for the get, but didn't work for the set.  Now I understand.  Thank you!!!!